# CSS: Using characters as decoration without busting the page margin

Tags: css

I'm trying to design a page header as below, going for a 1980s terminal aesthetic. The header has three elements on the same row, aligned left, centre, and right, with dash characters filling in the space between. I'm using `::before` and `::after` on the centre element to draw the dashes.

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out these points though:

1. How do I keep the dashes within the bounds of their container i.e. not spilling over the `<body>` margin?
2. I've separately set a background colour on `Left` and `Right` to hide the dashes behind them. This feels messy. Is there a better way?
3. It looks like the answer is "not without Javascript", but is there a way using HTML/CSS to make these elements align to the fixed-width character spacing, for instance by making `<body>` be a fixed even multiple of `ch` in width?

Code is on JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qm04hL1z/2/

```html
<body>
  <div class="header-outer">
    <div class="left-elem">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="center-wrapper">
      <div class="center-elem">
        Center
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-elem">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
   Hello, I am some content
  </p>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 2ch;
  margin-right: 2ch;
}
.header-outer{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.left-elem, .right-elem {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.left-elem {
  left: 0;
  padding-right: 1ch;
}

.right-elem {
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 1ch;
}

.center-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: wrap;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
.center-elem {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
.center-elem::before, .center-elem::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content:
  '-----------------------------------'
  '-----------------------------------';
}
.center-elem::before {
  padding-right: 2ch;
  right: 100%;
}
.center-elem::after {
  padding-left: 2ch;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dash characters are being used as decoration rather than content one way of getting a fully responsive header, with the potential for almost the same look, is to use linear gradient backgrounds instead. That way everything is self-adjusting number of dashes-wise.

It is not perfect - if the viewport width is not a complete multiple of ch for example you may get left with the odd part-dash (but that could happen with real characters too). But this method has avoided the 'hack' (is it a hack?) mentioned in the question of putting background colors on the headings. This could still be tried of course if it gives a neater result.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 2ch;
  margin-right: 2ch;
}
.header {
  --h: 0.1em; /* set to the height of the dash that you'd like */
  --l: 4ch; /* the number of characters in the lefthand heading */
  --c: 6ch; /* the number of characters in the center heading */
  --r: 5ch; /* the number of charater in the righthand heading */
  
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black calc(var(--l) + 1ch), transparent calc(var(--l) + 1ch), transparent calc(50% - ((var(--c) + 1ch) / 2)), black calc(50% - ((var(--c) + 1ch) / 2)), black calc(50% + ((var(--c) + 1ch) / 2)), transparent calc(50% + ((var(--c) + 1ch) / 2)), transparent calc(100% - (var(--r) + 1ch)), black calc(100% - (var(--r) + 1ch)), black 100%), linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 1ch, transparent 1ch, transparent 2ch);
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto, 2ch var(--h);
  background-position: 0 calc(0.5em + var(--h)), 0 calc(0.5em + var(--h));  
}

.header div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.left-elem {
  left: 0;
}

.right-elem {
  right: 0;
}

.center-elem {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="left-elem">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="center-elem">
      Center
    </div>
    <div class="right-elem">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
   Hello, I am some content
  </p>
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I went with setting a solid background colour and simplifying the dash-generator to make it look more like `------`. Does the job nicely!
https://jsfiddle.net/fgsrcm90/